# What version of debian has the 2.6.15 kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, debian, gnu

What version of debian has the 2.6.15 kernel? I am searching for this info and cannot find a chart that shows the debian version and the kernel that it uses. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Its actually a good question, its too bad it was down voted. Its not readilly apparent when searching for "debian 2.6 kernel".

Answer (score 1):

```
% rmadison linux-image-amd64
 linux-image-amd64 | 2.6.32+29       | squeeze           | amd64, i386
 linux-image-amd64 | 3.2+46~bpo60+1  | squeeze-backports | amd64, i386
 linux-image-amd64 | 3.2+46          | wheezy            | amd64, i386
 linux-image-amd64 | 3.13+56~bpo70+1 | wheezy-backports  | amd64, i386
 linux-image-amd64 | 3.13+56         | jessie            | amd64, i386
 linux-image-amd64 | 3.14+57         | sid               | amd64, i386
```

Previous versions unsupported now.

Answer (score 0):

Debian Etch, during late 2006.

[source - I have one running]